How to implement "selectable" items in a large List?
I have a list of approximately ~1000 items where each item(s) can be selected or unselected i.e something like ui preview here

My implementation (simplified) is essentially this
@State private var selectedIds: UUID[] = []

List {
  Section {
    // Header View
  }

  Section {
    ForEach(items) { item in
      let isSelected = selectedIds.contains(item.uuid)
      ItemView(item: item, isSelected: isSelected, selectedIds: $selectedIds)
    }
  }

  Section {
    // Footer
  }
}

So in essence, different styling gets applied to selected items and they all get a binding to selected id array where they will either add their own id or remove it when user taps on a "checkmark".
This works well in general, but I noticed an issue when I do the following:

I select first list item
I scroll really fast to the middle of the list (past many items)
I select another item

After I select 2nd item list "jumps" / "readjusts", not sure how to explain it, but I end up in a random section of it and my selected item is way up. So it feels as if while I was scrolling really fast, some items were not "rendered / included in a list" and after I select 2nd item, state change triggers list to "refresh?" loading in all those previous items?
Not sure how to work around this and keep selection smooth

Maybe this is because the list is being re-evaluated with every change to the state variable? How about if you add a flag to each item, so that only the affected ItemView will need to repaint. Then remove selectedIds from the parent view, of course.

Add an isSelected property in the object which represents an item. Calling contains in each ForEach iteration is terribly expensive.
Very simple example:
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isSelected = false
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var items = [Item(), Item(), Item(), Item(), Item(), Item(), Item(), Item(), Item(), Item()]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($items) { $item in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: item.isSelected ? "checkmark" : "circle")
                    .tint(item.isSelected ? .green : .primary)
                
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(item.isSelected ? Color.green : Color.gray).opacity(0.3)
            .onTapGesture { item.isSelected.toggle() }
        }
    }
}


Did the trick nicely, thank you!
